# Colsum new dataframe

Tags: r

With this command it is possible to have a dataframe with the sum of every column

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), stock = c(3,1,4), bill = c(1,0,1), bear = c(3,2,5))

dfsum <- data.frame(colSums(df[-1]))
```

However this dataframe has only one column.

How is it possible to produce a dataframe with 2 column one with col names and second with the frequencies?

Comment: `dfsum <- data.frame(n=names(df)[-1], s=colSums(df[-1]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
stack(colSums(df[-1]))

  values   ind
1      8 stock
2      2  bill
3     10  bear
```

Or using `tibble`:

```
enframe(colSums(df[-1]))

  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 stock     8
2 bill      2
3 bear     10
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `tidyverse` approaches with `summarise_at` and `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-id), sum) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything())
#   name value
#1 stock     8
#2  bill     2
#3  bear    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try `apply`.

```
apply(df[-1], 2, sum)
```

Result

```
stock  bill  bear 
    8     2    10
```

For `data.frame`

```
(df2 <- data.frame( freq = apply(df[-1], 2, sum)))
 df2$var <- rownames(df2)
```

Result

```
var   freq
stock    8
bill     2
bear    10
```